# query to include spring batch job param value along with job execution data

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-batch

For a Spring batch job, I have job params such as `requestName` & `responseId` which is in `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS` table.

```
JOB_EXECUTION_ID | KEY_NAME | STRING_VAL 
2   |             responseId             | f5e1b3e9
2   |             requestName            | DUMMY
```

I am retrieving details about the Job Execution with the following query:

```
SELECT je.JOB_EXECUTION_ID, 
       je.START_TIME, 
       je.END_TIME, 
       je.STATUS, 
       je.EXIT_CODE, 
       je.EXIT_MESSAGE, 
       ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID, 
       ji.JOB_NAME,
       --add requestName STRING_VAL
FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION je
INNER JOIN BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS p ON je.JOB_EXECUTION_ID = p.JOB_EXECUTION_ID
INNER JOIN BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE ji ON je.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
WHERE p.KEY_NAME = 'responseId' AND p.STRING_VAL = 'f5e1b3e9'
```

How can I populate the value of the `requestName` in my query? So for JobExecution id 2, its returns an additional columns `REQUEST_NAME` with value `DUMMY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MO6H just join in another instance of `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS` like this:

```
SELECT je.JOB_EXECUTION_ID, 
   je.START_TIME, 
   je.END_TIME, 
   je.STATUS, 
   je.EXIT_CODE, 
   je.EXIT_MESSAGE, 
   ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID, 
   ji.JOB_NAME,
   p2.STRING_VAL AS `REQUEST_NAME` -- add requestName STRING_VAL
FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION je
INNER JOIN BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS p ON je.JOB_EXECUTION_ID = p.JOB_EXECUTION_ID
INNER JOIN BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE ji ON je.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
JOIN BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS AS p2 ON p2.JOB_EXECUTION_ID = p.JOB_EXECUTION_ID        
WHERE p.KEY_NAME = 'responseId' 
    AND p.STRING_VAL = 'f5e1b3e9'
    AND p2.KEY_NAME = 'requestName'
```

please let me know if this doesn't do what you want and I'll try to help further.

Comment: @MO6H I just realized you wanted the extra column to show as `REQUEST_NAME`, I just modified my answer so the column will show up as `REQUEST_NAME` and then give you the value you are looking for